# How to resolve the "Unusual traffic" error with calls from appengine to gdata

Tags: google-app-engine, gdata

### App-engine CAPTCHA code

Googles GData is asking Google-app-engine for a CAPTCHA code.

How to enter a code OR reset things?

### Error message

All has been working fine for about 1 year, but then I got this "Unusual traffic" error yesterday.

My logs show a link to the page: "Unusual traffic from your computer network"
i.e. support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640

What is also strange, almost all the errors are calls that "Write" to Gdata, most "Reads" work just fine.

The call to:

```
com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.insert
```

causes the error:

> com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException

I am using the gdata style spreadsheet API

Also the load has been low, load several times the current load has worked fine in the past.

### Issue

I created an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6237

Answer (score 0):

Took a few hours - but this worked:

a) Added the App-Engine IP addresses to support.google.com/websearch/contact/ban

b) Creating the issue in the GData issue tracker may have helped.

Is hard to be sure which of these resolved the problem, but is now working again.

Comment: I suppose none of the two, I suppose, sorry... :-) - Google  “unusual traffic” error is by definition a "temporary" error: after a few hours Google resets the algorithm to detect "unusual traffic" from your IP...